# Android how to observe Opera and Dolphin Browsers or all the Browsers

Tags: android, browser, web-controls, contentobserver, parental-control

I am implementing web blocking(parental control) in android. I am able to observe the url click(whenever user wants to visit some website) of only Android's Default Internet Browser using following code:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, new MyContentObserver(mHandler, getApplicationContext()));
```

But I am not able to observe other Browser's like Opera and Dolphin.

Please tell me How I can listen for these Browsers?

If I have to give something other than Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI ?

Comment: Rather obviously, someone can make a custom build of a browser which does not expose this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uri `content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks` for chrome browser. That way you can support two browsers.

Anyone can come up with their own browser with no API support hence you can not make an app for all browsers.